# Android Wear File does not appear

Tags: file, sensors, wear-os

I created a file to read the sensors of my Android Wear. I can tell it is working because my storage is being filled up, but I can't see the folder of the readings. Can you help me out finding out what is wrong with the code?

```
    public class Logging extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

DecimalFormat df =new DecimalFormat("##.##");


Boolean flag=true;
FileOutputStream outputStream;


TextView displayReading1;
TextView displayReading2;
TextView displayReading3;
TextView displayReading4;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  final File Project=getDir("Project", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(!Project.exists())
        Project.mkdir();
   File fileWithinProject=new File (Project+"/","Project.txt");
    if(!fileWithinProject.exists())
        try {
            fileWithinProject.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    // final File file=new File (dirPath,"Project.txt");
  /*  File file = new File(dirPath, "Project.txt");
    try {
        if (!file.exists())
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_logging);
    Button start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.StartButton);
    Button stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.StopButton);
    //BUTTON START
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flag=true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Start Recording Readings",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("File in: "+ Project), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();







        }
    }); {


    }
    //BUTTON STOP
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flag=false;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Done recording readings",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });{

    }
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor accSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    Sensor rotSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
    Sensor gravitySensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
    Sensor gyroSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor((Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE));

    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accSensor, 100000000);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, rotSensor, 100000000);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, gravitySensor, 100000000);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, gyroSensor, 100000000);

    displayReading1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acc_sensor);
    displayReading2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rotational_sensor);
    displayReading3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gravity_sensor);
    displayReading4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gyro_sensor);

    displayReading1.setTextSize(14f);
    displayReading2.setTextSize(14f);
    displayReading3.setTextSize(14f);
    displayReading4.setTextSize(14f);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_logging, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onSensorChanged (SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        displayReading1.setText("Accelerometer (m/s2): " +"\nX"+" " +df.format(event.values[0]) + "\nY"+" " + df.format(event.values[1]) + "\nZ"+" " + df.format(event.values[2]));
    float X11=event.values[0];
    float X12=event.values[1];
    float X13=event.values[2];
    if( flag) {
        try {
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("current location newFile.getAbsolutePath()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            outputStream = openFileOutput("Project.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(((df.format(X11) +  df.format(X12) +   df.format(X13)
            )).getBytes());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException f) {
            System.out.println("Exception");

        }
    }
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR)
        displayReading2.setText("Rotational Vector: " + "\nX"+" " + df.format(event.values[0]) + "\nY"+" " + df.format(event.values[1]) + "\nZ"+" " + df.format(event.values[2]));
    float X21=event.values[0];
    float X22=event.values[1];
    float X23=event.values[2];
    if( flag) {
        try {
            outputStream=openFileOutput("Project.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(("Rotational Vector : " +"\nX"+" " +df.format(X21) + "\nY"+" " + df.format(X22) + "\nZ"+" " + df.format(X23)).getBytes());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException f) {
            System.out.println("Exception");

        }}
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY)
        displayReading3.setText("Gravity (m/s2): " + "\nX"+" " + df.format(event.values[0]) + "\nY"+" " + df.format(event.values[1]) + "\nZ"+" " + df.format(event.values[2]));

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE)
        displayReading4.setText("Gyroscope (rad/s): " + "\nX"+" " + df.format(event.values[0]) + "\nY"+" " + df.format(event.values[1]) + "\nZ"+" " + df.format(event.values[2]));
    float X31=event.values[0];
    float X32=event.values[1];
    float X33=event.values[2];

    if( flag) {
        try {
            outputStream = openFileOutput("Project.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(("Gyroscope (rad/s): " + "\nX" + " " + df.format(X31) + "\nY" + " " + df.format(X32) + "\nZ" + " " + df.format(X33)
            ).getBytes());
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gyroscope (rad/s): " + "\nX" + " " + df.format(X31) + "\nY" + " " + df.format(X32) + "\nZ" + " " + df.format(X33), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException f) {
            System.out.println("Exception");

        }

    }
    if (!flag){
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}




@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}



}
```